# Mocking When a service method is called

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a SpringBoot app, where I have some tests. I have this Junit test:

and the test:

```
        public class FindHotelDataRequestTransformerTest {


            @Autowired
            private BackendHotelService backendHotelService;

            private FindHotelDataRequestTransformer transformer;

            @Before
            public void setUp() {
                transformer = new FindHotelDataRequestTransformer( backendHotelService);
            }

        @Test
        public void theTest() {
            mock(BackendHotelService.class);
when(transformer.getHotelApplicationName()).thenReturn("NameMocked");
...

        }
    }
```

That is based in these classes:

```
public abstract class HotelDataRequestTransformer {



    private final BackendCredentialsService backendCredentialsService;

    public HotelDataRequestTransformer(BackendCredentialsService backendCredentialsService) {
        this.backendCredentialsService = backendCredentialsService;
    }

    public String getHotelApplicationName() {
        return backendCredentialsService.getHotelApplicationName();
    }


}




    @Component
    public class FindHotelDataRequestTransformer extends HotelDataRequestTransformer {


        public FindHotelDataRequestTransformer(BackendHotelService backendHotelService) {
            super (backendHotelService);
        }
    ..
    }
```

But when I run the test I got a Nullpointer in the line

```
return backendCredentialsService.getHotelApplicationName();
```

so it seems that Mocking.when does not work

Comment: You need to mock the result of calling any method of that object, otherwise mockito won't know what to give back. So you need a `when(mockedObject.getterMethod()).thenReturn()` statement to continue past that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return from the mock itself rather than the class under test

```
backendHotelService = mock(BackendHotelService.class); // also use the mock created :)
when(backendHotelService.getHotelApplicationName()).thenReturn("NameMocked");
```

Answer (score 0):

transformer is not a mocked object you are creating a new transformer.

backendHotelService is the mocked object.

Try:
`when(backendHotelService.getHotelApplicationName()).thenReturn("NameMocked");`